# How to unpack values into message text using smtplib?

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm feeding a list of tuples that contain results from a sql query into my email.  I want to be able to format the email to print out the lines in the `msg` list in the following format:

```
SUBJECT LINE: xxxxx
File name: 'Blah Blah Blah' Sent to Pivot at: '3:30 p.m.'
File name: 'Blah Blah Blah' Sent to Pivot at: '3:30 p.m.'
File name: 'Blah Blah Blah' Sent to Pivot at: '3:30 p.m.'
File name: 'Blah Blah Blah' Sent to Pivot at: '3:30 p.m.'
File name: 'Blah Blah Blah' Sent to Pivot at: '3:30 p.m.'
```

Here is the code:

```
def send_email(recipient_list, missing_list):
    msg = ['File name: {0} '
           'Sent to Pivot at: {1}\n'.format(element[1],
                                            element[2]) for element in missing_list]
    msg['Subject'] = 'Alert!! Handshake files missing!'
    msg['From'] = r'm****@r**.com'
    msg['To'] = recipient_list

    s = smtplib.SMTP(r'mail.r**.com')
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg)
    s.quit()
```

My input will be in the form of a list of tuples containing three items, [(id, file_name, timestamp)]

Comment: I don't understand your question, what should your result look like?

Comment: @user1767754 I will edit the main body to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're missing the knowledge of some basic data structures in Python.

This is pretty close:

```
msg = ['File name: {0} '
       'Sent to Pivot at: {1}'.format(element[1],
                                      element[2]) for element in missing_list]
```

But you'll want to join it together in a single string.  Perhaps something like this:

```
body = '\n'.join(msg)
```

I'm not sure what else you're trying to do with `msg`.  You've created it as a `list`, but then are trying to assign values to keys as though it were a `dict`.  Why not just use local variables such as `subject`, and `from`?

It seems that from the `smtplib` [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) that you'll also need to include `From:` and `To:` in the body of the email.  Look at [this example](https://pymotw.com/2/smtplib/#sending-an-email-message) for a bit higher level abstraction of how to do that with `smtplib`.

I know I haven't completely re-written your code into a working version here, but hopefully this at least gets you closer.

Comment: You're right, I still had some of the original `MIMEText` code which looks for dictionary items.  Thanks!